# How do I update WooCommerce template files in my theme?

Tags: theme-development, templates, woocommerce-offtopic

WordPress beginner here - my site seems to have some outdated template files which I think are the cause of some functionality issues the site is experiencing.

Particularly, there are bundled outdated template files for the plugin WooCommerce. As far as I can tell, this is a fairly common problem for this plugin and they've even created a 'system status' page to show you exactly which template files are out of date.

Looking at this system status, I can clearly see that the template file 'variable.php' is out of date. This matches a problem I'm having where items aren't being added to the cart.

Now I'm fairly new to WordPress but if I understand right from [this](http://speakinginbytes.com/2014/02/woocommerce-2-1-outdated-templates/) article, these template files are just that - templates. They're all the same with slight revisions in each version, and I need to copy the actual contents over from my variable.php file over to the newly updated variable.php.

But then the article goes on to say this:

*"If you’ve found templates that are outdated you need to copy over the new templates to your theme and then make any changes you made to the previous template to this new template."*

I've found the templates that are outdated, but where do I find these 'new' updated templates? Is there an online resource that specializes in updating these files? If I'm right about how this works, this question should be easy. If I'm not, please correct me.

Comment: As a note: I'm having a hard time deciding if this belongs in the wordpress.stackexchange, but I think that it does since my problem seems to be outdated template files causing my plugin, specifically WooCommerce, to not work, and not my plugins causing WordPress not to work.

Comment: I found this but I'm a little wary... 

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php 

before I go and implement this file I found on the internet into a working WordPress, is this the file that I'm looking for?

Comment: this is really a woocommerce question and would probably be best asked in their support forum, as 3rd party plugins are off-topic here. these outdated templates are all specific to woocommerce and are not general WordPress templates.

Comment: WooCommerce support forum is a joke. This aside, couldn't this happen to any plugin? That is, it's not plugin specific? If this is the case it seems that it's more of an issue with the handling of plugins through WordPress than a single plugin problem. As I understand it WooCommerce created their system status page that analyzes a WP as a tool for WordPress, not necessarily for their plugin.

Comment: woocommerce's template system is specific to their plugin, they changed their own template system between versions which is why old *woocommerce* templates need to be updated. this is very much specific to woocommerce only.

Comment: You're right then, my apologies. I had an incorrect understanding of how WooCommerce operates. What's the proper action I should take for this question, deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outdated files are in your theme's woocommerce folder (unless the theme has stored them elsewhere, but that is the default). You don't *need* this folder per se and can rename it (which is the more temporary way than flat-out deleting it) and WooCommerce will work. If you purchased the theme you could also contact their support and see about purchasing an upgrade because if the theme has been updated for compatibility.

If there were important customizations in your templates then begins the super-fun job of comparing the old templates to the new ones (which are in the plugin WooCommerce's templates folder).

When WooCommerce 2.0 was released I had to save a client site whose checkout process was totally broken by outdated theme templates. The original theme people had copied *all* of the WooCommerce templates in lieu of just the ones they wanted to modify. In the end I removed all but maybe 3 of the override templates.

Comment: You were absolutely right! Unfortunately this didn't fix my issue, but did remove the error message. What a nightmare. I'm currently in the process of re adding 175 WooCommerce products that overwrite the same tables as the theme - meaning they break each other. Awful.